# React Native avoiding absolute textinput

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, textbox

I have absolute and hidden text input it is show onpress a button.I want it to be on the top of keyboard and grid toolbar if exist.
I have used avoidkeyboardview component but it dosen't work on another way I played on style css it has worked but it has ignored the tool bar which displayed from the device I played on the style again and used native base container it has worked on my device by calculate the keyboard height and use it as margintop for text input container plus 70pt the toolbar height on my device it is fine but on another it is not like the image is there any solution.

[see the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eu8gNuWcqUXU4s2lKX9s3oVII5U4fYO5/view?usp=drivesdk)